# open iPhone in foreground from the watch os2

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, foreground

Is there any way to bring iPhone application into the foreground by pressing a button in the Apple watch

any way other than handoffs!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not currently possible. WatchConnectivity just serves to exchange data between the two devices, not for changing their statuses.

Of course you may activate a local notification from the watch on the iPhone upon clicking which the coupled application goes to the foreground, but it shall still require an action by the user on the iPhone.